# Como fazer um collapse em Ionic?

Tags: ionic, angular, collapse

eu estou tentando fazer um Collapse e esta mais ou menos assim:

HTML

```
<ion-content>
```

{{topicos.name}}

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let aulas of topicos.get_classes" [hidden]="deixainvisivel" menuClose ion-item (click)="openClass(aulas.id)">{{aulas.name}} <b>{{aulas.time}}</b></ion-item>
```

TS

```
  Collapse(id){
console.log(id)
this.idtopic = id;
this.deixainvisivel = !this.deixainvisivel;
```

}

O problema é que ele fecha todos os "tópicos", tenho q dar um jeito dele fechar só os q tem o ID do item divider

Comment: Tente conferir este artigo: https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-accordion-list-in-ionic/